# How can I map some parameters to be optional?

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapped-types

## Context:

I'm trying to write a function that will allow the user of the function to define a certain type using *no typescript type assertions* (just plain old javascript syntax). Basically, I'm trying to write something like React's PropTypes but I want to map the type defined with these "PropTypes" to a type that can be enforced with typescript.

Maybe it's easier to understand what I'm trying to do by seeing the code. Below `defineFunction` is a function that returns a function that takes in an object defined by "PropTypes"`.

```
interface PropType<T> { isOptional: PropType<T | undefined> }
type V<Props> = {[K in keyof Props]: PropType<Props[K]>};
interface PropTypes {
  string: PropType<string>,
  number: PropType<number>,
  bool: PropType<boolean>,
  shape: <R>(definer: (types: PropTypes) => V<R>) => PropType<R>
}

// the only purpose of this function is to capture the type and map it appropriately
// it does do anything else
function defineFunction<Props, R>(props: (types: PropTypes) => V<Props>, func: (prop: Props) => R) {
  return func;
}

// define a function
const myFunction = defineFunction(
  // this is the interface definition that will be mapped
  // to the actual required props of the function
  types => ({
    stringParam: types.string,
    optionalNumberParam: types.number.isOptional,
    objectParam: types.shape(types => ({
      nestedParam: types.string,
    }))
  }),
  // this is the function definition. the type of `props`
  // is the result of the mapped type above
  props => {
    props.objectParam.nestedParam
    return props.stringParam;
  }
);

// use function
myFunction({
  stringParam: '',
  optionalNumberParam: 0,
  objectParam: {
    nestedParam: ''
  }
});
```

Here is the resulting type of `myFunction` found by hovering over the type in VS Code:

```
const myFunction: (prop: {
    stringParam: string;
    optionalNumberParam: number | undefined;
    objectParam: {
        nestedParam: string;
    };
}) => string
```

## Question:

There is an issue with the code above--`optionalNumberParam` is correctly defined as `number | undefined` but it is not actually optional!

If I omit the `optionalNumberParam`, the typescript compiler will yell at me.

[image]

#### Is there anyway to assert that a type is optional instead of just `T | undefined`?

---

Replying to `cale_b`'s comment:

> Just a thought - have you tried optionalNumberParam?: types.number.isOptional

Yes and it's invalid syntax:

[image]

And to clarify, this `defineFunction` should let the user define a type using *no typescript type assertions*--instead everything should be inferred using mapped types. The `?` is typescript only. I'm trying to write this function so that--theoretically--javascript users could define proptypes and still have the typescript compiler enforce those proptypes.

Comment: @cale_b see the updated answer. Added a screenshot there because I couldn't add one in the comments

Comment: Great clarification.  Thanks, and good luck! Out of my depth at this point... :)

Comment: I don't have a great solution for you; you may find you need to specify two object literals: one for required parameters and the other for optional ones, where the result is the intersection of two mapped types (one with and one without the question mark).

Comment: @jcalz that's not a bad idea for a workaround. I'm starting to think that what I'm asking isn't possible yet. I'm gonna open an issue on the typescript github and I'll link to it once I finish the proposal

Comment: @jcalz Here is a proposal I just submitted: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20984

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, closest workaround I can do involves that two-object-literal solution I mentioned:

```
interface PropType<T> { type: T }
```

First I removed `isOptional` since it does you no good, and second I added a property with `T` in it since TypeScript can't necessarily tell the difference between `PropType<T>` and `PropType<U>` if `T` and `U` differ, unless they differ *structurally*.  I don't think you need to use the `type` property though.

Then some stuff I didn't touch:

```
type V<Props> = {[K in keyof Props]: PropType<Props[K]>};
interface PropTypes {
  string: PropType<string>,
  number: PropType<number>,
  bool: PropType<boolean>,
  shape: <R>(definer: (types: PropTypes) => V<R>) => PropType<R>
}
function defineFunction<Props, R>(props: (types: PropTypes) => V<Props>, func: (prop: Props) => R) {
  return func;
}
```

Now, I'm creating the function `withPartial`, which takes two parameters of types `R` and `O` and returns a value of type `R & Partial<O>`.

```
function withPartial<R, O>(required: R, optional: O): R & Partial<O> {
  return Object.assign({}, required, optional);
}
```

Let's try it out:

```
const myFunction = defineFunction(
  types => withPartial(
    {
      stringParam: types.string,
      objectParam: types.shape(types => ({
        nestedParam: types.string,
      }))
    },
    {
      optionalNumberParam: types.number
    }
  ),
  props => {
    props.objectParam.nestedParam
    return props.stringParam;
  }
);
```

Note how I split the original object literal into two: one with required properties, and the other with optional ones, and recombine them using the `withPartial` function.  Also note how the user of `withPartial()` doesn't need to use any TypeScript-specific notation, which is I think one of your requirements.

Inspecting the type of `myFunction` gives you:

```
const myFunction: (
  prop: {
    stringParam: string;
    objectParam: {
      nestedParam: string;
    };
    optionalNumberParam?: number;
  }
) => string
```

which is what you want.  Observe:

```
// use function
myFunction({
  stringParam: '',
  //optionalNumberParam: 0,  // no error
  objectParam: {
    nestedParam: ''
  }
});
```

Hope that helps; good luck!